# Sql query to use table whose name changes every day

Tags: mysql, sql

So i am using sqlloader application in IIQ that uses sql query to read csv files. File is dropped on our shared folder everyday but name is changed everyday i.e. subuser102, subuser103, subussr104.

How do i write a query when the file name is not constant?

Comment: why is there a so may tables anyhow. when your tablenames have an algorithm try to implement ot in a procidure

Comment: A process run by a business team drops a single file on our location but it they replace the old file with new file, same data but different name.

Comment: but he file name has a pattern, so rebuild it and make a dynamic sql with prepered stazement

Comment: *How do i write a query when the file name is not constant?* MySQl have no instruments for to scan the filesystem for file presence and for its filename. So the name must be either provided or generated (for example, based on the name of the last file which was loaded). While proviging server easily loads the file.